# assignment operator not always called

Tags: c++, constructor, variable-assignment

I have a template class with two functions, extracts shown below;

```
template<class TYPE, class ARG_TYPE>
int MyClassT<TYPE, ARG_TYPE>::Add(ARG_TYPE newElement)
{ 
    TYPE Element = newElement; <--- TYPE operator= not called, shallow copy
'
'
}
```

and

```
template<class TYPE, class ARG_TYPE>
void MyClassT<TYPE, ARG_TYPE>::SetAt(int nIndex, ARG_TYPE newElement)
{ 
,
,
m_pData[nIndex] = newElement;  <--- TYPE operator= is called, deep copy

'
'
}
```

Why does the first case result in a shallow copy, yet the second case in a deep copy?  I'm assuming a copy constructor is being substituted in the first case, but don't see why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `TYPE Element = newElement; <--- TYPE operator= not called, shallow copy`

This should call copy-constructor, not `operator=()`, as this is not assignment statement. This is initialization.

- Initialization invokes copy-constructor. In initialization, a new object is *constructed*.
- Assignment invokes `operator=()`. In assignment, old object is *updated* with a given value.

So, have you defined a copy-constructor for `TYPE`?

Comment: I have a copy constructor, but it had a second parameter added and hence was not being used as a default copy constructor.  Must re-read stroustrup one of these days, been too long.

Comment: Out of interest, does the same hold true for type conversion operators, e.g. if I have `TYPEA& operator=(TYPEB& value)` should I also have the conversion constructor `TYPEA(TYPEB& value)`

Comment: @Shane: Since your question as well as comment is vague, or atleast, not clear enough to me, I would like to know what is `TYPE` and `ARG_TYPE` in your example? Without knowing the actual type, or atleast the relation between them, I've to type a lot to completely answer your question, considering all possible cases!

Comment: no worries, this is something I can test very quickly myself.  TYPE can be any type, as the template is a generic container.  ARG_TYPE is a reference to TYPE, I should've used TYPE&, but have inherited some bad habits from an old MFC code base.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm assuming a copy constructor is being substituted in the first case, but don't see why.

That is exactly what is happening. The C++ standard mandates this behaviour. You should make your copy constructor do the same thing as your assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
TYPE Element = newElement;
```

This is actually construction, not copy operator syntax. As such, it will invoke the copy constructor.

```
TYPE Element;
Element = newElement;
```

Will invoke the assignment operator as you expect as the = is invoked on the constructed object - likewise, all the objects in your array are constructed, which is why the assignment operator is invoked.